# PostgreSQL ошибка линковки программы на С++ и libpq undefined reference

Tags: c++, postgresql

Не получается скомпилировать программу, например такую:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

int main() {

    int lib_ver = PQlibVersion();

    printf("Version of libpq: %d\n", lib_ver);

    return 0;
}
```

> D:>gcc postgr_test.c -I"D:/POSTGR~1/12/include"
>   -L"D:/POSTGR~1//12/lib" -lpq

Вывод:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   C:\Users\BEA7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2KwRqW.o:postgr_test.c:(.text+0xf):
>   undefined reference to `PQlibVersion' collect2.exe: error: ld returned
>   1 exit status

Компилятор:

> D:>g++ -v 
>   Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe Target: mingw32 Configured with: ../src/gcc-8.2.0/configure
>   --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5' --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-isl=/mingw --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls --disable-build-format-warnings Thread model: win32 gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5)

Операционная система: Windows 10 Pro 1909

Comment: Если убрать ` -lpq`, ошибки те же самые, или другие?

Comment: Убрал, ошибка осталась той же.

Comment: Тогда скорее всего у вас `libpq.a` не под ту архитектуру (компилятор 32-битный, а библиотека 64-битная, или наоборот).

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался, проблема решилась переустановкой компилятора.

Comment: Угу, новый компилятор похоже 64-битный, а тот был 32.

Answer (score 0):

Все, я решил проблему простой переустановкой компилятора. 
Старый компилятор я брал с сайта mingw, новый взял с posix-tread от [сюда](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/).